# download data in excel from database without GridView

Tags: asp.net

I Have to fetch data from database and download in Excel format without DataBind() on any Control.

Is There any Possible way to accomplish this task?

Comment: I had tried Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application(); But I want export data without binding of gridview.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you have tried? You said you want to export to excel without any control. If so, you can pass the data to DataTable and use it

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to download in xlsx format, I can recommend [ClosedXml](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml) - none of the nightmare of interop and requiring Excel on the same machine. Quite easy too - see this example: [Adding DatatTable to Worksheet (ADO.net)](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki/Adding-DataTable-as-Worksheet).

See also this example for [delivering an Excel file with ASP.net](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki/Deliver-an-Excel-file-in-ASP.NET)